# Add Facebook login to existing login syste

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, sdk

I have problem! Im trying add Facebook login on my website but some stuff in my script is encoded. Problem is that in facebook login for detect user is logged in or not use this code:

```
if ($user)
 {
   /* Some code for logged in user
 }
```

And on myy website I using this code:

```
if(User::isLoggedIn())
 {
   /* some code
 }
```

My question is how can I change this to dont need change every file where is User::isLoggedIn()

Comment: Maybe you can add the facebook method to your own function... I don't know. Something like `public static function isLoggedIn() { if(!$user) { return false; } else /* do your own thing`. Need more context though....

Answer (score 1):

into your User class, isLoggedIn method, add

```
public function isLoggedIn() {
    global $user
    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Problem is that I cant change nothing because this file is encoded

Comment: If you have to use User::isLoggedIn you must have access to the User class. Else, you must replace `User::isLoggedIn` in your project with (example) `FacebookAuth::isLoggedIn` where you can do whatever you need (you may replace using Netbeans or other editor - it's just one click).

Answer (score 0):

What I do is link the user Facebook account whith the user login account adding a field in my db user table, and then, when the user is logged via facebook, I check if his id is associated with a user account in my db.

If so, I init the user class with logged in activated.